# xsd build failed when enumeration value contains plus and minus

Tags: java, xml, xsd

We used xsd XML schema to generate the java class, when set the enumeration as following, there will no file generated (also no error reported).Part of the xsd schema:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="UserTimeZoneData">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="UTC"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="GMT+9"/>
            <xsd:enumeration value="GMT-9"/>
 </xsd:restriction>     
</xsd:simpleType>
```

I test and verify some cases and find that when I remove GMT+9 or GMT-9, then it will work. It seems that GMT+9 and GMT-9 cannot exist at the same time.
How can i do to solve this issue? Need your help, thanks.

Comment: What library are you using the generate the Java classes? What version?

Comment: Hi, we use jaxb-xjc.jar verion1.0.

Answer (score 2):

It's not able to generate unique names for the constants as it tries to replace the special characters (with respect to Java variable naming) with underscore, it's left with duplicate variable names.

```
GMT+9 -> GMT_9
GMT-9 -> GMT_9
```

Thus there are 2 variables with the same name, this is where it fails.

We can force JAXB to use certain variable name by using `typesafeEnumMember`

Take a look at the following example

**XSD**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    jaxb:version="2.0">

    <xsd:simpleType name="UserTimeZoneData">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="UTC" />
            <xsd:enumeration value="GMT+9">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:appinfo>
                        <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember name="GMT_PLUS_9" />
                    </xsd:appinfo>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
            <xsd:enumeration value="GMT-9">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:appinfo>
                        <jaxb:typesafeEnumMember name="GMT_MINUS_9" />
                    </xsd:appinfo>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:enumeration>
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

**Generated Java Files**

UserTimeZoneData.java

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlEnum;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlEnumValue;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * <p>Java class for UserTimeZoneData.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * <p>
 * <pre>
 * &lt;simpleType name="UserTimeZoneData">
 *   &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string">
 *     &lt;enumeration value="UTC"/>
 *     &lt;enumeration value="GMT+9"/>
 *     &lt;enumeration value="GMT-9"/>
 *   &lt;/restriction>
 * &lt;/simpleType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 */
@XmlType(name = "UserTimeZoneData", namespace = "")
@XmlEnum
public enum UserTimeZoneData {

    UTC("UTC"),
    @XmlEnumValue("GMT+9")
    GMT_PLUS_9("GMT+9"),
    @XmlEnumValue("GMT-9")
    GMT_MINUS_9("GMT-9");
    private final String value;

    UserTimeZoneData(String v) {
        value = v;
    }

    public String value() {
        return value;
    }

    public static UserTimeZoneData fromValue(String v) {
        for (UserTimeZoneData c: UserTimeZoneData.values()) {
            if (c.value.equals(v)) {
                return c;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(v);
    }

}
```

Reference : https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html/Developing_Applications_Using_JAX-WS/files/JAXWSCustomTypeMappingEnum.html

Comment: It works. Thanks very much! And sorry for that i have no ability to vote.

Comment: @Bright.H You do have the ability to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).